# Proof that $(A-B)\cup(B-C) = (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C^c) \cap (B\cap C)^c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I drew some Venn diagram's and constructed a couple of sets and this claim seems to hold (correct me if I am wrong).  I have difficulties proving this however. I have tried to rewrite the lefthandside using the set identities, but no dice so far. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by simplifying LHS:
$$\begin{align}
(A-B) \cup (B-C) &= (A \cap B') \cup (B \cap C') \\
 &= ((A \cap B') \cup B) \cap((A \cap B') \cup C') \\
 &= ((A\cup B) \cap (B' \cup B)) \cap((A \cup C') \cap (B' \cup C')) \\
 &= (A\cup B) \cap (A \cup C') \cap (B\cap C)'
\end{align}$$

Here we have used

- $(A - B) = (A \cap B')$
- Distributive property of $\cap$ and $\cup$
- Demorgon's Law: $(B' \cup C') = (B\cap C)'$

Comment: Thanks! For the record you also used the complement's law and the identity law in the third step (sorry for nitpicking)

Comment: Oh I didn't know its name :)